# C# Hashtable storing DataSets

Tags: c#, hashtable

I am trying to figure out how do you store and retrieve DataSets with a hashtable.

Here is what I tried, but I get invalid cast exception when I try it.  Also how can I loop through that hash and get the key as well as the data set

```
Hashtable myHash = new Hashtable();
myHash.Add("1", someDataSet);
foreach (DataSet ds in myHash)
{
     lblMessage.Text = lblMessage.Text + " - Hash ID + ds[0].TableName";
}
```

I should probably add that first 2 lines of code pass, it crashes on the third.

Comment: Any reason you're still using non-generic collections? If you were using a generic `Dictionary<,>` you'd find out why this is a problem at *compile* time...

Comment: Never heard of Generic Dictionary

Comment: Have you used generics *at all*? They were introduced in C# 2.0. I would very strongly advise you to learn about the newer versions of C# - you'll find all kinds of things easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better way to convert a hashtable to datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590534/better-way-to-convert-a-hashtable-to-datatable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in myHash)
{
    DataSet ds = (DataSet)entry.Value;
    lblMessage.Text = lblMessage.Text + " - Hash ID + ds[0].TableName";
}
```

Dictionary will hold `key` and `value` as the form of `DictionaryEntry` struct, so you can't cast from `DictionaryEntry` to `DataSet` actually your dataset is a Value added to Hashtable so it will be located in `DictionaryEntry.Value` property

**Edit** As mentioned in comment DirectCast is appropriate

Comment: Why use `as` rather than a direct cast? If the value is *not* a `DataSet`, that indicates a bug which would ideally prompt a failure as soon as possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet I usually prefer as keyword with null check to avoid exception at runtime.

Comment: Bad idea. In most cases, you're casting because you *know* what you expect the type to be, and any other type would indicate a bug. What you're doing now is effectively swallowing exceptions - it's much better to *get* an exception at runtime than to carry on as if everything were fine, when actually there's a detectable error.

Comment: have him look at this link this is a similar question asked on `SO` but the OP wanted to use DataTable same concept applies. that is if the OP can follow and understand the code on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590534/better-way-to-convert-a-hashtable-to-datatable

Comment: Trust me I know the answer.. perhaps you should look up on the Internet who `Jon Skeet` is .. and then you will understand why many of us respect his knowledge perhaps you should too GrassHopper`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I know Jon very well, Author of `C# in Depth` I luv his book too, but that doesn't mean we shouldn't give our thoughts when Jon is there right? Of course I agree Jon will give better solution than me, but sill there is a chance that OP can learn there is some other way of doing this from my answer. makes sense right?

Comment: @JonSkeet I follow this practice since letting the `Exception` to happen and Catching it reduces my App performance for the code which is being executed very often. but still I Log the issue saying `ds is null in BlahBlahMethod()` for latter debug purpose. Is my approach right or do you have some suggestions for me?

Comment: I am not going to debate with you on this I think you missed the key point of what the issue is or potential issue is with your recommended solution.

Comment: Everyone is entitled to their opinion and sharing what they believe to be the right answer.  Problems arise when people like you DJ KRAZE come looking for drama and picking fights that are not necessary, please stop.  Thank you both to Jon Skeet and Sriram Sakthivel for sharing you knowledge.  Have a good day.

Comment: No Drama here just straight forwardly stating my OPINION.. Good luck Bagzli happy coding

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: No, I don't think that's a good idea at all. It spreads your error handling all over the place whereas excpetions can be caught more centrally. Note that performance would only suffer if the exceptions were thrown - and if you are throwing so many exceptions that it makes a difference due to casts, you have *correctness* issues which are far more serious than the *performance* issues. (Personally in many cases I wouldn't even catch such exceptions. I'd rather have an app crash than continue with bad data.)

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, that sounds good. Will consider your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently trying to iterate through all the key/value pairs, but casting them to `DataSet`. You can fix this easily as:

```
foreach (DataSet ds in myHash.Values)
```

If you actually want the key as well, you can change your iteration variable to be of type [`DictionaryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry.aspx), but there's no need to use that unless you need the keys.

... but I'd *strongly* suggest that you move to a generic collection instead.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how a generic collection would work?

Comment: @Bagzli: If you've never used generics before, it's worth setting some time aside to learn about them from scratch - a single example won't be nearly as useful to you.